# How to set dynamic data in react?

Tags: reactjs

I have got series of data that contains some objects in one array(json file) and it will be shown by react.

```
const Library = [
{
name: "Star Wars"
},
{
name: "Harry Potter"
},
{
name: "Lord of the Rings"
},
{
name: "Star Trek"
},
{
name: "The Fault in Our Stars"
},
{
name: "Number the Stars"
},
{
name: "Blue"
},
{
name: "Act Da Fool"
},
{
name: "The Gilded Cage"
},
{
name:
  "To Get to Heaven First You Have to Die (Bihisht faqat baroi murdagon)"
},
{
name: "Lebanon"
},
{
name: "Tenderness"
},
{
name: "It"
},
{
name: "Locked Out (Enfermés dehors)"
},
{
name: "Waterloo Bridge"
},
{
name: "Set It Off"
},
{
name: "Nil By Mouth"
},
{
name: "Monte Carlo"
},
{
name: "Treasure of the Four Crowns"
},
{
name: "Donnie Darko"
},
{
name: "Cry-Baby"
},
{
name: "Juan of the Dead (Juan de los Muertos)"
},
{
name: "Constant Nymph, The"
}
];

// Main App Component
 class App extends React.Component {
 constructor(props){
 super();
 this.state = {
library: null,
perPage: 1,
currentPage: 1,
maxPage: null,
filter: ""
 };
}
componentDidMount() {
 this.reorganiseLibrary();
 }

// Calculates the library
   reorganiseLibrary = () => {
   const { filter, perPage } = this.state;
   let library = Library;
   console.log(library)

   if (filter !== "") {
    library = library.filter(item =>
    item.hotelinfo.hotelsearch.realname.toLowerCase().includes(filter)
   );
   }

  library = _.chunk(library, perPage);

   this.setState({
    library,
    currentPage: 1,
    maxPage: library.length === 0 ? 1 : library.length
    });
   };

  // Previous Page
   previousPage = () =>
   this.setState(prevState => ({
   currentPage: prevState.currentPage - 1
  }));

// Next Page
  nextPage = () =>
  this.setState(prevState => ({
  currentPage: prevState.currentPage + 1
 }));

// handle filter
   handleFilter = evt =>
  this.setState(
   {
    filter: evt.target.value.toLowerCase()
  },
  () => {
    this.reorganiseLibrary();
  }
);

 // handle per page
  handlePerPage = (evt) =>
  this.setState({
   perPage: evt.target.value 
   }, () => this.reorganiseLibrary());

 // handle render of library
  renderLibrary = () => {
  const { library, currentPage } = this.state;
  if (!library || (library && library.length === 0)) {
  return <div>No results</div>;
  }
   return library[currentPage - 1].map(item => (
    <div key={item.hotelinfo.hotelsearch.realname}>{item.hotelinfo.hotelsearch.realname}</div>
   ));
   };

 render() {
    const { library, currentPage, perPage, maxPage } = this.state;
     return (
     <div className="library">
      <h1>Library</h1>
      <div className="d-flex">
          <div className="flex-fill">
              <label className="library__filter-label">Filter</label>
              <input value={this.state.filter} onChange={this.handleFilter} />
          </div>
          <div className="flex-fill text-right">
              <label className="library__per-page-label">Per page</label>
              <input placeholder="per page" value={this.state.perPage} onChange={this.handlePerPage} />
          </div>
      </div>
      <div className="library__book-shelf">
          {this.renderLibrary()}
      </div>
      <div className="d-flex">
          <div className="flex-fill">
            {currentPage !== 1 && (
              <button onClick={this.previousPage}>Previous</button>
            )}
          </div>
          <div className="flex-fill text-right">
            {(currentPage < maxPage) && (
              <button onClick={this.nextPage}>Next</button>
            )}
          </div>
      </div>
      <div className="library__page-info text-right">
          {this.state.currentPage} of {this.state.maxPage}
      </div>
  </div>
  );
  }
  }
 ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

The data of Library is going to be dynamic and the data will be sent from another page to this page by  ajax request  but as you can see data is set statically. How to set data of Library dynamiclly.
I try below code biy there is this error : 
 ReferenceError: Library is not defined

```
Component { 
  constructor(props){ 
  super(); 
  this.state = { 
  Library:[],
  library: null,
   ..... 
    };
  $.ajax({ 
  url:"/json.bc", 
  type:"post",
  data:{ 
  cityid:"1182348",
  rooms:JSON.stringify({"rooms":[{"adultcount":"1","childcountandage":"0"}]}), 
    },
  success:(result)=>{ 
  this.setState({Library: eval(result)}); } }) }
  . . . 
  }
```

**Edited code :**

```
class App extends React.Component {
 constructor(props){
 super();
 this.state = {
 Library:[],
 library: null,
 perPage: 1,
 currentPage: 1,
 maxPage: null,
 filter: "",
 };
 }
  componentDidMount() {
  $.ajax({ 
  url:"/test1.bc", 
  type:"post",
   data:{
    cityid:"1182348",
    rooms:JSON.stringify({"rooms":[{"adultcount":"1","childcountandage":"0"}]}),
                },
   success:(result)=>{ 
   this.setState({Library: eval(result)}); } 

   })}
   componentDidMount() {
     this.reorganiseLibrary();
    }

// Calculates the library
   reorganiseLibrary = () => {
   const { filter, perPage } = this.state;
   let library = Library;
   console.log(library)

    if (filter !== "") {
      library = library.filter(item =>
      item.hotelinfo.hotelsearch.realname.toLowerCase().includes(filter)
     );
     }

     library = _.chunk(library, perPage);
     this.setState({
      library,
      currentPage: 1,
      maxPage: library.length === 0 ? 1 : library.length
       });
      };

    // Previous Page
       previousPage = () =>
       this.setState(prevState => ({
        currentPage: prevState.currentPage - 1
       }));

   // Next Page
   nextPage = () =>
    this.setState(prevState => ({
     currentPage: prevState.currentPage + 1
   }));

   // handle filter
    handleFilter = evt =>
    this.setState(
     {
       filter: evt.target.value.toLowerCase()
     },
     () => {
      this.reorganiseLibrary();
     }
    );

  // handle per page
    handlePerPage = (evt) =>
     this.setState({
     perPage: evt.target.value 
}, () => this.reorganiseLibrary());

   // handle render of library
   renderLibrary = () => {
    const { library, currentPage } = this.state;
if (!library || (library && library.length === 0)) {
  return <div>No results</div>;
}
return library[currentPage - 1].map(item => (
  <div key={item.hotelinfo.hotelsearch.realname}>{item.hotelinfo.hotelsearch.realname}</div>
));
};

render() {
const { library, currentPage, perPage, maxPage } = this.state;
return (
  <div className="library">
      <h1>Library</h1>
      <div className="d-flex">
          <div className="flex-fill">
              <label className="library__filter-label">Filter</label>
              <input value={this.state.filter} onChange={this.handleFilter} />
            </div>
          <div className="flex-fill text-right">
              <label className="library__per-page-label">Per page</label>
              <input placeholder="per page" value={this.state.perPage} onChange={this.handlePerPage} />
          </div>
      </div>
      <div className="library__book-shelf">
          {this.renderLibrary()}
      </div>
      <div className="d-flex">
          <div className="flex-fill">
            {currentPage !== 1 && (
              <button onClick={this.previousPage}>Previous</button>
            )}
          </div>
          <div className="flex-fill text-right">
            {(currentPage < maxPage) && (
              <button onClick={this.nextPage}>Next</button>
            )}
          </div>
      </div>
      <div className="library__page-info text-right">
          {this.state.currentPage} of {this.state.maxPage}
      </div>
  </div>
);
 }
 }
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
getData = (callback) => {
 $.ajax({ 
   url:"/json.bc", 
   type:"post",
   data:{ 
   cityid:"1182348",
   rooms:JSON.stringify({"rooms":[{"adultcount":"1","childcountandage":"0"}]}), 
    },
   success:(result)=>{ 
    callback(eval(result))
   }
   . . . 
   }
}

setData = () => {
 this.getData(data => { this.setState({ Library: data }) } )
}
```

Comment: assignment to undeclared variable getData

Comment: where should I exactly add them?

Comment: Add them into the class dlrectly. And you can call this.setData() where you want

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the ajax call in `componentDidMount()` set state.

```
 componentDidMount() {
    $.ajax({ 
  url:"/json.bc", 
  type:"post",
  data:{ 
  cityid:"1182348",
  rooms:JSON.stringify({"rooms":[{"adultcount":"1","childcountandage":"0"}]}), 
    },
  success:(result)=>{ 
  this.setState({Library: eval(result)}); } }) }
  . . . 
  }
  }
```

Comment: Thank @TRomesh. I did it but there is this error again.

Comment: Library is not defined

Comment: class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
 super();
 this.state = {
    Library:[],
    library: null,
    perPage: 1,
    currentPage: 1,
    maxPage: null,
    filterT: "",
    filterTp: "",
  };
}
componentDidMount() {
    $.ajax({ 
  url:"/test1.bc", 
  type:"post",
                    data:{
                        cityid:"1182348",
                        rooms:JSON.stringify({"rooms":[{"adultcount":"1","childcountandage":"0"}]}),
                    },
  success:(result)=>{ 
  this.setState({Library: eval(result)}); } 

}) }
.
.
.
}